# Load Jenkins Pipeline Shared Library from different repository

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

```
(root)
+- src                     # Groovy source files
|   +- org
|        +- barHelper.groovy     # for org.Bar class
+- vars
|   +- foo.groovy          # for global 'foo' variable

I have common class in another repository with name commonhelper.groovy 
(root)
+- src                     # Groovy source files
|   +- org
|        +- commonhelper.groovy
```

there was a method in commonhelper.groovy named methodA(). I want to used methodA() from commonhelper.groovy in barHelper.groovy

In the beginning of the file we tried to use import statements like package com.bar

Is there any solution to acheive this?

Comment: Did you try to use Global Pipeline Libraries configuration?